# Почему поехали блоки

Tags: html, css

Не могу понять почему так.

Проект:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6yBSacgA5Hba3hDWmRld0VLdEk/view?usp=sharing

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для класса `.tshr__item-pos` добавьте св-во `vertical-align: top;`.

Просто когда указываете элементы в ряд и задаете им свойство `display: inline-block` нужно не забывать про вертикальное выравнивание.

Comment: помогло, спасибо!